# Magento 1.9.2.1 Emails are not working

Tags: magento-1.9, email, ce-1.9.2.1

All emails are not working. My cron settings is below.
[image]

I have tried running it manually by this command

```
php - f c:\xampp\magento\cron.php
```

No error or exception is generated in magento and xampp server log file

Need Help.

Thank you

Comment: Are you tring to send mail via localhost ?

Comment: No I am trying to send via local smtp server

Answer (score 0):

You can check all cron job using [this magento extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html). Its shows error which is effect in your cron job

Answer (score 0):

You can try to little change in code may be it helps you .

/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php Line#1356,1450

//$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send(); Change To

```
      $mailer->send();
```